# How can I add a new column and fill said column in powershell using excel?

Tags: excel, powershell

(For this example I'm going to use the command Get-Service) When I do the command Get-Service, something like this is returned:

```
    Status    Name  
  Running    service1
  Stopped    service2
  Running    service3
```

I put the results of this command in an excel file, using the module ImportExcel

```
Get-Service | Select-Object Server, Status, Name |Export-Excel -path F:\file.xlsx
```

Notice that I added the column "Server" to the file. I need this column to be fieled with the name of a server from an array

```
$servers = @('Server1', 'Server2')
```

Meaning it would be something like this:

```
 Server     Status    Name  
 Server1   Running    service1
 Server1   Stopped    service2
 Server1   Running    service3
 Server2   Running    service1
 Server2   Stopped    service2
 Server2   Running    service3
```

Meanig that for each server I want to run the command get-servive, add the column with the server name to the excel file and fill each row of each service with the server name.
Here is what I have so far:

```
 $servers = @('Service1', 'Service2')
 $services=@(Get-Service).Count
 foreach($server in $servers)
 {
   for($i=0; $i -lt $services; $i++){
      #for each service add column with the server name
   } 
 }


 #at the end export everything to excel file
     $something|Export-Excel -path F:\file.xlsx
```

I'm not sure if my explanation made sence but if anyone could help me with this I would appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer with. I just needed to do something like this:

```
$servers = @('Server1', 'Server2')
$data = foreach($server in  $servers)
{
  Get-Service | Select Status, Name, @{l="Server";e={$server}}
}

  $data |Export-Excel -path F:\file.xlsx
```